# how to calculate gradient color by percent

Tags: graphics, colors, rgb

I have a float score, which is 0 to 1

I need translate this score to color,

0 is green

1 is red

0.5 should at the middle of green to red gradient color

and so on

how to write this? I have no idea.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

let gradient colour parameter be `t`,  `0.0 =< t =< 1.0`

```
colour = RGB(255 * t, 255 * (1 - t), 0)
```

Comment: Java friendly : Color.rgb((int)(255 * t), (int)(255 * (1 - t)), 0);

Answer (score 1):

Multiply the float by 255 to get your green value, and multiply (1-float) by 255 to get your red value. If you need to output a css color code, use rgb(x,y,z).